# Whats wrong with this sql statement?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am using MS ACCESS where I am changing the recordsource of the form in the afterupdate event of a combobox. Here is the sql query used

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM qryMIMATRIX WHERE qryMIMATRIX.A_LOCATION = " & Me.cboLocate.Value & ";"
```

cboLocate is the name of the combobox and qryMIMATRIX is the name of the query.
On afterupdate event of the I am prompted to enter parameter which is not desirable.Help me out..

Comment: I am pretty serious about my SQL Injection comment below. As your query stands you are open to a serious security problem. A combo box by default allows you to enter text manually not just select from a list. This means someone could enter something like....

somevalue; DROP TABLE blah blah....

Comment: Setting the combo's "Limit To List" property to Yes prevents injection into the RecordSource SQL statement.  However, Access' db engine isn't vulnerable to that `DROP TABLE` type of injection attack because it will only handle one statement ... you can't join 2 statements with a semicolon and expect the engine to execute both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a_loaction` field is string type you need to wrap value with quotes:

`"SELECT * FROM qryMIMATRIX WHERE qryMIMATRIX.A_LOCATION = '" & Me.cboLocate.Value & "'"`

Comment: Got answers in no time,really.Thanks!I hope I'll be able to figure out things this fast.

Comment: This one doesn't seem to be working,I used the same logic:"SELECT * FROM qryMIMATRIX WHERE qryMIMATRIX.A_LOCATION = '" & Me.cboLocate.Value & "' AND qryMIMATRIX.A_PRIORITY= '" & Me.cboPrior.Value &"'" A_PRIORITY is integer,from 1 to 5

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the query...

1. Read up on SQL Injection...right now, I'll wait.

   ...

   ...
2. Don't select * ..... not a good practice, specify the columns.
3. You probably need to quote the value from the combo box

Comment: I am sorry I'm ignorant but what is sql injection all about?I think I need to google about this.I will check that out.As of now, I think I can use the LimitToList property to Yes and that will be okay?

Comment: Yes, you should read up on it, it's important. Plus, it's easy to fix. There are hundreds (1000's probably) of articles that discuss it. Here is a good one. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/09/30/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Guard-Against-SQL-Injection-Attacks.aspx

Comment: Thanks.I'm going to check that but what about my query?